# Query Google Analytics Report using Postman has 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I follow the guide in here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

It works fine. But I would like to try with Postman.

This is my try:
Request: https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

Header: 
Authorization: Bearer ya29.Ezxxxxx

Content-Type: application/json

Body:

```
{"reportRequests": [
          {
            "viewId": "viewid",
            "includeEmptyRows": true,
            "dateRanges": [
              {
                "startDate": "7daysAgo",
                "endDate": "today"
              }
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "expression": "ga:sessions"
              }
            ],
              "dimensions": [
                {
                  "name": "ga:date"
                }
              ]

          }
        ]
}
```

But I got error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have any Google Analytics account.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The token I get from the code like this:

```
      var content = require('./project_key.json');
      var jwt = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
              content.client_email,
              null,
              content.private_key,
              ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']); 
      jwt.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
      var access_token = tokens.access_token;
      res.send(access_token);
```

It seems the permissions are not set. But I'm not sure how to set it up. I can get the token from the "private key file".

Any recommendation is really appreciate. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It's done.

I had to setup Google Analytics to work with the newly created Service Account:
        -Open Admin section of Google Analytics
        -Click on Users and create a new user in Analytics with the e-mail address provided by the Google API Service Account

and it resolved error 403.